Are threaded inserts actually weak?
I recently came across this video which purports to show that threaded inserts are vastly less durable than screwing directly into wood.
This seems incredibly suspect. A threaded insert ought to have more thickness of wood between each thread (of the insert; the failure point isn't in the metal), which I would think should be stronger. I believe the threads (that go into the wood) are also deeper, and I've certainly seen people pull ¼"×20 bolts straight through "threaded" holes in bare wood. I've also seen plenty of wood-workers use threaded inserts, but not so many using tapped threads in bare wood. I also wonder whether his testing is accurately reflective of real world forces that the joint would need to withstand. (He doesn't even connect anything, just drives a bolt straight into the insert.)
One point in particular is that the the video-maker only uses CA glue to secure the insert. Epoxy seems to be the standard, though I think I've heard of wood glue being used also. This makes sense as it seems the main force the glue needs to resist is shearing force (i.e. the insert trying to unscrew itself), and CA glue is known for having good tensile strength but very low shearing strength.
Are threaded inserts are really as weak as this video portrays? Have other sources compared to inserts installed with wood glue and/or epoxy? (I've looked, but couldn't find any such analyses.)

The video shows what the video shows. It's largely up to the individual to interpret the vid in context, rather than just taking the host's conclusions at face value. "A threaded insert ought to ... be stronger. I believe the threads (that go into the wood) are also deeper" Those are all valid points as far as they go, but there's a lot of gut feeling or 'it seems to me that...' with this sort of thing. In practice a lot of things aren't the way many/most assume — after all nearly everyone thought machine threads directly in wood would be weak, when in practice it's totally the opposite.....

"and I've certainly seen people pull ¼"×20 bolts straight through "threaded" holes in bare wood." Details matter hugely with this sort of thing. Even seemingly minor ones. I can assure you if the wood were strong-ish, the bolts were long enough, the pilot hole was drilled the right size (absolutely vital) and, v importantly, the screw had never been over-tightened, nobody would be pulling those bolts out of wood with their bare hands.... unless the person pulling was Steve Rogers maybe :-)

@Graphus, sure, I'm aware. What I'm really hoping to get out of this is information on the strength of inserts installed with wood glue and/or epoxy, because it feels to me (yes, I know, more subjectivity, but that's why I'm trying to find hard data!) that would be significantly more durable. Unfortunately I was unable to find any such content. FWIW, the pull-the-bolt-out demo I mention was with plywood (I don't know what species).

Re. the plywood, well obviously for starters that's plywood :-) Even with really top-notch stuff there's generally limited thickness to provide hold if going in through the face. And if this is into an edge there's lots of (more crumbly than typical) end-grain involvement.
